# QProcess passing arguments to a python Script

Tags: python, c++, qt, qprocess

```
from PIL import Image
def porcentaje(path):

    im = Image.open(path, "r")
    im.show()
    width, height = im.size
    type = im.mode
    format = im.format
    pixels=im.getdata()
    n = len(pixels)
   im=im.load()
   nblack = 0
   noblack=0

   for pixel in pixels:
       if pixel < 50:
           nblack += 1
       else:
           noblack+=1

porcentajefinal=(nblack*100)/n
print(porcentajefinal)
return(porcentajefinal)

(porcentaje(path))
```

mainwindow.cpp (QT Creator)

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

    QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
            tr("All Files (*)"));
     qDebug()<<path;

     QDir dir1("D:/QTCProjects/prueba");
     QFile file1("D:/QTCProjects/prueba/2_1.py");
     QString script1 = "D:/QTCProjects/prueba/2_1.py";
     QFile file2(script1);

     qDebug() << dir1.exists() << file1.exists() << file2.exists();
       //  these all result in true, true true
     QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
     myProcess->start("python.exe D:/QTCProjects/prueba/2_1.py" );
     myProcess->waitForFinished(-1);

      qDebug() << "myProcess:" << myProcess->readAll(); }
```

This python requires a variable called path to run and i get this variable in qtcreator with Qstring path, how i can give python this variable with Qprocess.

Comment: How do you pass the parameters to your script when you call it through cmd? It would help us if you show the part of how you read the parameters in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass arguments to a script through the terminal, the following structure is used:

```
python.exe /path/of/your_script.py arg1 arg2 ... argn
```

Then to obtain the parameter we must use sys.argv which is a list that stores the following:

```
['/path/of/your_script.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', ..., 'argn']
```

So in your case you should get the parameter through `sys.argv[1]`:

**2_1.py**

```
from PIL import Image
import sys

def porcentaje(path):

    im = Image.open(path, "r")
    im.show()
    width, height = im.size
    type = im.mode
    format = im.format
    pixels=im.getdata()
    n = len(pixels)
    im=im.load()
    nblack = 0
    noblack=0
    for pixel in pixels:
        if pixel < 50:
            nblack += 1
        else:
            noblack+=1

    porcentajefinal=(nblack*100.0)/n
    print(porcentajefinal)
    return(porcentajefinal)

path = sys.argv[1]
porcentaje(path)
```

On the side of Qt, python.exe is the main program, and the other parameters are the arguments, so your code must have the following structure:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "All Files (*)");
    qDebug()<<path;
    if(!path.isEmpty()){
        QDir dir("D:/QTCProjects/prueba");
        QFileInfo info(dir, "2_1.py");
        qDebug() << dir.exists() << info.exists();
        QProcess process;
        process.start("python.exe", QStringList()<< info.absoluteFilePath() << path);
        process.waitForFinished(-1);
        qDebug() << "myProcess:" << process.readAll();
    }
}
```